# Transforming one column into a new column in minimal number of queries

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I have a table on a server with fields `docid (bigint(20))`, `msgtext (longtext)` and others I don't care about.

What I want to do is run a function on the `msgtext` (which uses some regular expressions to clean `msgtext`) and then add the result back into the database in the newly created column `cleanMsgtext`. My goal is to optimize this, and ideally minimize my own memory requirements in the process.

To minimize the memory requirements the easiest thing to do would be to do this one step at a time. I.e. I'd pull down one row, run the function, and then push back the result. Of course that's a little extreme so it makes more sense for me to pull down the rows, say, 10,000 rows at a time to minimize the select queries. What I want to do is to try to minimize the update queries as well. I.e. My select query is something like

```
select docid, msgtext 
from db
where docid='1' or docid='2' or ... or docid='10000'
```

which I can easily do programatically by pulling down docids ahead of time or whatever (though maybe this is also stupid?). This alone causes and enormous speedup which I'm happy with.

What I wonder is if there is an equivalent way of doing this for updating the table. Can I just concatenate update messages in a similar fashion to create one query from multiple queries? I've read things where this is possible if you pull down the entire row each time, but for me the docid is a unique identifier so that seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

So in conclusion, I would like to select batches of size N, do my work on the data locally, then update again in batches of size N. Is this possible?

Comment: I know you are trying to be friendly but we concentrate on relevnt facts here. This will also work better for you because long questions care off and if you keep it short more people read it to the end.

Comment: Okay I'll try to keep it more to the point in the future. Thanks a lot for the ridiculously fast edit!